# Find geolocation of specified IP address using Google Geocoding instead of IP address of the request

Tags: google-geolocation

Is it possible to specify a certain IP address that we want to get the geolocation of it using Google Geocoding instead of relying on the IP address of the requester?

Comment: Did you find the answer yet ?

Comment: @NirmalrajRethinasabapathi not possible it seems